# How to properly use LIKE and '%%' in python to search a database list for a partial response stored in a placeholder variable?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, database, flask

```
search = request.form.get("search")

book = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE title = :search OR author = :search OR isbn = :search OR title LIKE :search",{"search": search}).fetchall()
```

This is a portion of my function. I want the user to be able to search for a book and store their result in "search", and I want to be able to pull any results from the database list that at least has the "search" even if the title isn't complete. Example, if the user is looking for a book titled "the fisherman" but the user only types in "the fisher" I want the query to be able to pull "the fisherman".

Comment: Try `title LIKE '%' + :search + '%'`. The equality condition for title is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
book = db.execute(text("SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE :search"),
                     {"search": f"%{search}%"}).fetchall()
```

The error was in my dictionary. To have a variable that the user inputs to be looked up using '% %' must be modified within the dictionary.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please add an explanation for long term value, and to help digest your code.  Code only answers are frowned upon on SO. Future visitors should be able to visit your post, and learn how to apply the knowledge shared to their own coding issues.  Posts with great explanations are also much more likely to be upvoted, and english is generally easier to read an digest than code. Thanks for your contribution.